# How to properly align background with before content

Tags: html, css, sass

I have this html structure:

```
<div class="single-apartment-typology-text">
  <span class="title-apartment primary-title text-animated">
    <div class="title">Testing</div>
    <div class="uptitle">
      <span> last 3 opportunity</span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

I've added a background `title-apartment` using the `:before` property. My goal is have the span within `uptitle` aligned to the border, the problem's that when I change the resolution the content doesn't stick to the right border:

[image]

This is my scss:

```
.title-apartment {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;

    .title {
       position: absolute;
       z-index: 2;
       display: block;
       left: 0;
     }

    &:before {
       content: "";
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       background-color: $yellow;
       left: 65px;
    }

    .uptitle {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        margin-right: 10px;
        background-color: $blue;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        transform: translateX(33.8%);

       span {
         display: block;
         font-size: 10px;
         font-weight: 600;
         text-transform: uppercase;
        line-height: 23px;
      }
  }
}
```

I tried to keep the span with the dark blue background attached to the right yellow background using the `translateX` property, but no luck so far.

Any idea to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're shifting your :before pseudo element right by 65px, the `.uptitle` element doesn't know where this is as it's a sibling rather than a child. The easiest thing to do is to set up a [css custom property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) to record how far you're shifting the `:before` pseudo element then shift the `.uptitle` element right by the same amount. If we use the `right` property then our reference point will be the right border but it'll have to be a negative value to then shift that element right. Hence the `calc` in there.

Marked up code below

```css
body {
  background: #BCB5AF;
}

.title-apartment {
  --left-shift: 65px; /* added this */
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.title-apartment .title {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
}

.title-apartment::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #E0CA36;
  left: var(--left-shift);
}

.title-apartment .uptitle {
  position: absolute; /*changed from relative to absolute */
  right: calc(-1 * var(--left-shift)); /*added this */
  z-index: 1;
  /*margin-right: 10px;  if you want this to be hard up agains the border then remove this. If you always want it to be 10px then keep it in */
  background-color: #444F5F;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  
}

.title-apartment .uptitle span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 23px;
}
```

```html
<div class="single-apartment-typology-text">
  <span class="title-apartment primary-title text-animated">
    <div class="title">Testing</div>
    <div class="uptitle">
      <span> last 3 opportunity</span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

P.S. I've assumed you want it hard up against the border hence I've removed the `margin-right` in the `.title-apartment .uptitle` rule but reinstate it if you want it always to be 10px from the edge.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve your goal is to do the following:

- set `width: 20%;` to the `.title` and
- set `width: 80%;` to the `.title-apartment::before`.

Does this solve your problem?

See the snippet below or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afemkjvb/31/).

```css
.title-apartment {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.title-apartment .title {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  width: 20%;
}

.title-apartment::before {
  content: "";
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  left: 65px;
}

.title-apartment .uptitle {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.title-apartment .uptitle span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 23px;
}
```

```html
<div class="single-apartment-typology-text">
  <span class="title-apartment primary-title text-animated">
    <div class="title">Testing</div>
    <div class="uptitle">
      <span> last 3 opportunity</span>
</div>
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood the problem but tested and without it you don't have that space

```
 .uptitle {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        margin-right: 10px; // TO REMOVE
        background-color: $blue; 
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        transform: translateX(33.8%);
```